# Adding an event to a running sched.scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

This code should create a thread which executes `sched.scheduler.run()`, and then schedule an event 5 seconds into the future. However, on Python 3.7.4 on macOS Catalina, the scheduled event callback does not run.

Is it expected that you can schedule events on a running `sched.scheduler`? I would assume you can since you are allowed to cancel queued events, and there is no exception thrown.

```py
import datetime
import sched
import threading
import time


class Schedule:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.scheduler.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def at(self, when, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        e = self.scheduler.enterabs(when.timestamp(), 0, callback, args, kwargs)
        return e


target = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5))

s = Schedule()
s.at(target, print, 'Ding!')

while True:
    print(time.time() - target.timestamp(), s.scheduler.queue)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

`run` doesn't do the infinite loop thing your expecting. It consumes the queue and without further events it then returns. Ergo, if run executes before 'Ding' is queued 'Ding' will sit in the queue until the end of days

Comment: Yes I think this is likely it. But I just tried scheduling an event for one year in the future before calling `run`, which should keep the scheduler running long enough to "Ding", right?

Comment: Ok, enqueuing a new event does not interrupt the event that was previously scheduled and is currently being waited for. So if you want to insert an event, you will need to basically stop the schedule and restart it.